# Django Using TabularInline in Admin Panel

Tags: python, django

I'm making a django app. It has multiple tests with multiple quesiton each. every question has an answer.

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


    def get_answer(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent')
    def __str__(self):
         return self.text
```

I'd like to be able to manage whole test (making/changing questions and answers) from one django admin "view".

I tried to do this like that:

```
admin.py

class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question


class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        QuestionInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

but it only allows me to change/add test's questions.

[image]

what should I change/add to be able to manage whole test - including answers managing system from one page ?

ofc I can do it by making another admin page:

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AnswerInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

But i would like to do it from only one page

Comment: If you have no problem using an external library, you should checkout django nested admin `https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin`

Comment: Thanks a lot @CynthiaOnyilimba , That's exacly what I was looking for. Works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin` it's might be what you are looking for.